# What is a pythonic way of using multiple fields for key evaluation during sorting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python3 removed the [`cmp` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter) which was used for comparison during sorting and replaced it with [`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).

The [`cmp_to_key` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) was introduced to be "primarily used as a transition tool for programs being converted from Python 2".

It is unclear to me how to recreate `cmp` behavior natively in python3 with `key`. For example, if I want to sort strings by length, with a tie-breaker by lexicographic order, I would write something like this:

```
def compare(word1, word2):
    if len(word1) > len(word2):
        return 1
    if len(word2) > len(word1):
        return -1
    if word1 < word2:
        return 1
    if word2 < word1:
        return -1
    return 0

myStrings.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(compare), reverse=True)
```

How can a comparison across objects be done in a python3-native way, meaning without `cmp_to_key`?

One thing I can think of is returning a more complex key, for example:

```
# This would return something like 5.12 for "hello" and 5.20 for "world"
def myKey(word):
    return len(word) + myLexicographicalValueFunction(word)/100

myStrings.sort(key=myKey, reverse=True)
```

But this doesn't seem to scale well as you add more variables to compare.  What is a pythonic way of using multiple fields for key evaluation during sorting in python3?

Comment: In a nutshell, the "pythonic" way is for the key function to return a tuple of values—one for each value being compared—and the let Python's tuple comparison logic take care of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that specific comparison, you could use a tuple as the key:

```
myStings.sort(key=lambda s:(-len(s),s),reverse=True)
```

For object classes, you would probably need to implement a comparison operator (e.g. `def __lt__(self,other):` method) to let the sort know how to compare them natively.

If you can't modify the object class or if your comparison is very complex, you could create a wrapper object which implements the `__lt__()` method using a lambda that you povide:

```
class ObjectComp:
    def __init__(self,instance,cmp):
        self.instance = instance
        self.cmp      = cmp
        
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.cmp(self.instance,other.instance)
        
def cmpsort(objects,cmp):
    return [obj.instance for obj in sorted(ObjectComp(o,cmp) for o in objects)]


s = cmpsort([1,11,21,12,13],cmp=lambda a,b:a%10>b%10)
print(s)
[13, 12, 1, 11, 21]
```

Comment: 1. Ah, so the solution is a tuple with as many fields as necessary for tie-breaking?

2. And for objects, would you also need to implement `gt`,`eq`, etc for that to work?

Comment: @fvrghl 1: yes.  2: not needed because the `key` callable (the lambda in this answer) contains the logic for deciding order.  It will take that element, say `e`, create a tuple `(-len(e), e)` for every element, and sort then accordingly.  Therein lies your `gt`, `eq`, `lt` logic needed for your sort.  I think you still need to implement those `gt`, `eq`, `lt` to be used with ordered collections.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complicated comparison, you are applying a distinctive meaning to the string that in pythonic terms probably means it would benefit from its own type. Python is happy to allow you to subclass generic types so in your case you probably want something like this:

```
class InterestingWord(str):

    def __lt__(self, x: str) -> bool:
        if len(self) < len(x):
            return True
        return super().__lt__(x)

    def __gt__(self, x: str) -> bool:
        if len(self) > len(x):
            return True
        return super().__gt__(x)
```

Thus:

```
In [2]: InterestingWord("00") > InterestingWord("1")
Out[2]: True

In [3]: "00" > "1"
Out[3]: False
```