# python sort a 2d list without using lambda

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array, lambda

So I have this list:

`lst = [[7, 0], [4, 4], [7, 1], [5, 0], [6, 1], [5, 2]]`

I want to sort it accordingly: in reverse order for the first index, and if 2 items have the same first index, then in normal order by the second index

So the output will be:

`lst = [[7, 0], [7, 1], [6, 1], [5, 0], [5, 2], [4, 4]]`

I can do this using lambda function:

```
lst = [[7, 0], [4, 4], [7, 1], [5, 0], [6, 1], [5, 2]]
lst.sort(key = lambda x : (-x[0], x[1]))
```

But if I dont want to use lambda, how would I do it? I have this template, but not sure how to proceed from here:

```
lst = [[7, 0], [4, 4], [7, 1], [5, 0], [6, 1], [5, 2]]
def compare(input):
    # put code here
lst.sort(key = compare(#what and how do I pass as input))
```

Comment: return the same thing as your lambda: `def compare(x): return (-x[0], x[1])`

Comment: `lambda` is basically a shortcut for `def` where you don't have to name your function.

Comment: `lst.sort(key=compare)` is correct.  You don't pass any input.  You're just passing the function.  The `sort` function will call YOUR function and pass the correct input.

Comment: Adding to the above comments, in `list.sort` you pass function object. You don't call it. `lst.sort(key=compare)` should be written.

Comment: I strongly recommend not calling your **key** function  `compare`. Sorting functions usually accept as input, either a **key** function, or a **comparison** function. In python2, it was possible to sort by passing a **comparison** function. In python3, it's no longer possible, you should always pass a **key** function; but there is [functools.cmp_to_key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) to wrap a comparison function into a key function. Calling your **key** function "compare" is confusing, both for you and for people who will read your code.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend not calling an argument or a variable `input`. Name `input` is already the name of a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) in python. Shadowing the name of a builtin is very bad practice and can lead to unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Python's sort is "stable" so it will keep items with the same sort key in their original relative order.  This means that you can perform two sorts, starting with the least significant order and obtain the result you are looking for:

```
lst = [[7, 0], [4, 4], [7, 1], [5, 0], [6, 1], [5, 2]]

from operator import itemgetter
lst.sort(key=itemgetter(1))              # ascending 2nd index
lst.sort(key=itemgetter(0),reverse=True) # descending 1st index (stable)

print(lst)
[[7, 0], [7, 1], [6, 1], [5, 0], [5, 2], [4, 4]]
```

If you need to use a custom comparison function, you will find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66323716/5237560).